# What is the (first, second and higher) order asymptotic distribution?

Tags: distributions, terminology, asymptotics, definition

As the title, I am looking for the concept of this term. However, I failed to obtain a clear explanation on the web.

Any comments would help.

Comment: There is such a thing as asymptotic distribution of order statistics. Are you sure that the inverted word order is meaningful?